# Azure Event Grid Webhook validation handshake

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I would like to know if it is possible to have Azure Web Site (ASP.NET Core) and Azure Event Grid with Webhook to the Azure Web Site in the same ARM Template?
For the first time, there is no possibility to validate Webhook.

Of course, I can split it into the two ARM Templates and deploy 1st ARM with the Application, deploy the Application and add the Event Grid Webhook.

Is it some other workaround here? I can use Event Grid Schema or Cloud Events Schema.

Answer (score 0):

another workaround can be used to create an event subscription with some destination resource handler (for instance: storage queue) and then updating for your webhook handler.

Comment: Hmm but in this case, I still need two ARM templates am I right?

Comment: this workaround requires one (common) arm template for deployment and after that one REST PATCH request for updating an existing event subscription, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2020-04-01-preview/eventsubscriptions/update